# using cxf in osgi: Provider org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl not found

Tags: osgi, cxf

I am trying to publish some web services (using EndpointImpl.publish()) but I am gettings this error:

Provider org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl not found

the cxf-bundle is installed:

```
[  79] [Active   ] [Created  ] [   50] Apache CXF Bundle Jar (2.4.3.fuse-01-02)
```

an extract of the osgi:headers shows the imported package

```
Import-Package = 
javax.jws,
javax.persistence;version="[1.1,2)",
javax.servlet;version="[2.5,3)",
javax.xml.bind,
javax.xml.bind.annotation,
javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters,
javax.xml.datatype,
javax.xml.namespace,
javax.xml.parsers,
javax.xml.transform,
javax.xml.transform.stream,
javax.xml.validation,
javax.xml.ws;version="[2.2,3)",
javax.xml.ws.soap;version="[2.2,3)",
javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing;version="[2.2,3)",
org.apache.commons.lang;version="[2.5,3)",
org.apache.commons.logging;version="[1.1,2)",
org.apache.cxf.jaxws;version="[2.4,3)",
org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi;version="[2.4,3)",  <--- imported
org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing;version="[2.4,3)",
org.apache.felix.gogo.commands;version="[0.10,1)",
org.apache.openjpa.enhance;version="[2.2,3)",
org.apache.openjpa.util;version="[2.2,3)",
org.osgi.framework;version="[1.5,2)",
org.osgi.service.blueprint;version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)",
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml;version="[3.0,4)",
org.springframework.context;version="[3.0,4)",
org.springframework.context.support;version="[3.0,4)",
org.w3c.dom,
org.xml.sax

Require-Bundle = 
org.apache.cxf.bundle
```

I am not sure what else I need to do.

in case it is important. the container is a karaf 2.2.7

to address pooh's answer:

1- cxf-bundle is exporting this package: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi;version="2.4.3.fuse-01-02"

2- bundle was started. the error was during runtime.

3- the manifest was created using maven-bundle-plugin  which should create the entire list

4- the error happen while creating a webservice endpoint:

```
TopologyIFPortType impl = new TopologyWS();
    String addressTopology = "http://localhost:" + port
            + "/nsp/webservice/topology";
    topologyEndpoint = (EndpointImpl) Endpoint.create(impl);
    topologyEndpoint.getFeatures().add(new WSAddressingFeature());
    topologyEndpoint.publish(addressTopology);
```

the complete trace:

```
 javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$ConfigurationError: Provider      org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$2.run(FactoryFinder.java:130)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.doPrivileged(FactoryFinder.java:220)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:124)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.access$200(FactoryFinder.java:44)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$3.run(FactoryFinder.java:211)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.doPrivileged(FactoryFinder.java:220)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:160)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:43)
at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.create(Endpoint.java:41)
at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.create(Endpoint.java:37)
at org.opennaas.extensions.idb.webservice.WebServiceHolder.startTopology(WebserviceControl.java:78)
at org.opennaas.extensions.idb.webservice.WebServiceHolder.start(WebserviceControl.java:60)
at org.opennaas.extensions.idb.webservice.WebserviceControl.startWebservices(WebserviceControl.java:32)
at org.opennaas.extensions.idb.shell.StartWebservices.doExecute(StartWebservices.java:16)
at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.OsgiCommandSupport.execute(OsgiCommandSupport.java:38)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:35)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:78)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:474)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:400)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)
at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.Console.run(Console.java:240)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: @ santiagozky: can you please update the status of this. because I got the same issue... thanks

Comment: hi @kandy. Sorry but this is from 2012, I don't remember anything of this. as Christian mentioned my version of CXF was old at the time, not it is very obsolete.

Comment: Its ok I'll check, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The version of CXF you use seem to be quite old. You should try with the current release 2.6.1. In 2.6 a lot of OSGi improvements were introduced.

You can install it using:
features:chooseurl cxf 2.6.1
features:install cxf

Comment: I am working in a plugin for a system that uses that version. I will try to see if it is possible to upgrade. But it doesn't depend on me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, OSGi gives you full access to the information which bundle uses which package etc. You only have to know how to ask the system to give you the info you need for debugging the problem. 
Unfortunately I am not familiar with karaf console commands, I am working more with [ProSyst's mBeddedServer OSGi framework](http://www.prosyst.com/index.php/de/html/content/97/Products-OSGi-Implementation/), but since all this is standard in OSGi, I can tell you what to look for and you can find the needed commands in karaf.

So, check the following: 
1. Is Apache cxf bundle successfully installed? Is it in the "active" state?
(from your posting it seems that it is)

1. What is the version of the org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi package that it exports?
   **This is different from the cxf bundle version!!!**
   In order to see the package version, look inside the manifest of the cxf bundle, and look for the Export-package header.
2. Is your bundle installed and started successfully? Is it in the active state?
   If the error "Provider not found" appears during starting of your bundle, then your dependencies are not matching the provided packages from the cxf bundle, see point 2. 
   If, however, the error appears during runtime, it could have several causes:
3. You haven't imported all needed packages in your manifest. Try using analysis tools which can generate the manifest for you based on your source code.
   or:
4. The code which does the publishing is located e.g. on the system classpath and uses the system classloader, which in OSGI due to modularity and security reasons doesn't have access to the bundle classloaders. 
   Check what is provided by the system classpath instead of as OSGi bundles. Anything there which uses Class.forName or other reflection methods won't work in the modular OSGi framework.

There are also other possibilites, but you'll need to provide more info. Was there an exception stack trace? What classes are involved in this piece of code and where on the classpath are they located? etc.